# c programming scanf

Tags: c, morse-code

I been given this assignment and this is the code I made so far. This code is only accepting one letter when it should do more than on letter, so I could type in a word and it would be in Morse code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  char input[80], str1[100];

  fflush(stdin);
  printf("Enter a phrase to be translated:\n");
  scanf("%c", &input);
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(input); i++)
    {
      str1[j] = '\0';
      switch(toupper(input[i]))
        {
          ..................
        }
      j++;
    }
  printf("\nMorse is \n %s\n", str1);
  fflush(stdout);
  //printf("%s\n ",morse);
  free(morse);
}
```

Comment: @Nikolai: for reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: You allocate to little memory for the morse string! Why not declare and initialize it as an array, like `char morse[] = "...";`

Comment: First, please mark homework questions as such. Then, a hint - static table indexed by ASCII code, mapping characters to Morse code strings.

Comment: Ah, OK, totally missed that ... thanks.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov do not use or ask for the usage of the `[homework]` tag - and the homework status is disclosed in the description.

Comment: Yes, yes. Read the comments, dude.

Comment: [fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html).

Answer (score 6):

Your scanf has `%c` which expects only one character. Use `%s` to read a c-string:

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

Arguments to `scanf()` are of pointer type. Since a c-string name is the pointer to the first element, there's no need to say address-of (`&`).

if you were to read only a single character, you need to use `&`.

E.g.:

```
scanf("%c", &input[i]); // pass the address of ith location of array input.
```

Comment: You have corrected the pointer argument in your answer, but it would be good to explicitly mention the wrong type of the original.

Comment: @DanielFischer Updated with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, very good. But I won't unupvote just to reupvote the edited version ;)

Answer (score 2):

Read a string using `%s` not `%c`. Also a character string is already a pointer, no need to get its address. So transform this:

```
scanf("%c", &input);
```

into:

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%c", &input);` will read a single character, you're probably looking for `scanf("%s", input);`

Comment: Remove the `&` in front of input.

Comment: Indeed, quick copy / paste mistake